# A problem with remapping ctrl key

Tags: bind, keys

I need to bind ctrl key instead of winkey.

I tried do remapping with file usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc and with setkeycodes, but nothing helped me. It is not working with combinations as ctrl + c and ctrl + v.

So, I did not find any instruction to do it.

Comment: what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Last version, 18.10

Comment: 0k.. can you elobarate more on what you want to achieve exactly.. in general it is easily possible.. if you elobarate more.. its easy to answer or easy to provide the links to the answera those already exist..

Comment: Install `gnome-tweaks` with the command `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` and then try the options in Keyboard & Mouse -->> Additional Layout Options -->> Alt/Win Key Behaviour https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P1eK.png if you need other kind of binding.. clearly explain in your question..